# Is the following SQL statement correct?

Tags: sql, select, greatest-n-per-group

GOALS (~1700 rows)

```
YEAR COUNTRY   NAME              NUM_GOALS
-------------------------------------------
2018 England   Harry Kane                6
2018 France    Antoine Griezmann         4
2014 Argentina Lionel Messi              4
2014 Brazil    Fred                      1
2010 Germany   Thomas Muller             5
2010 Japan     Shinji Okazaki            1
1992 England   Gary Linekar              6
```

CHAMPIONS (~500 rows)

```
YEAR    COUNTRY NAME    ROLE
-------------------------------------------------
2018    France  Didier Deschamps    Manager
2018    France  Hugo Lloris Goalkeeper
2018    France  Paul Pogba  Midfielder
2014    Germany Joachim Loew    Manager
2014    Germany Mesut Ozil  Midfielder
2014    Germany Miroslav Klose  Forward
2002    Brazil  Da Silva    Midfielder
1994    Brazil  Da Silva    Midfielder
1998    France  Didier Deschamps    Midfielder
```

Write a query to identify the golden boot winner (highest goal scorer) in each world cup.

What I am unsure about whether I should include a MAX clause.

I'd be grateful for extra clarification and help with this, or if my query needs any tweaking.

This is what I cam up with:

```
SELECT NAME, YEAR, MAX(NUM_GOALS) as NUM_GOALS 
FROM GOALS;
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: This is the last one before i accept the changes. Please if you could tell me if its right for what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Yuur query is not valid SQL: you have aggregate and non aggregate columns in the `SELECT` clause, but no `GROUP BY` clause.

If you want the name of the top-scoring person for each year, then this is a greatest-n-per-group problem. You don't want to *aggregate* rows, but instead *filter* them. A typical option is to use a correlated subquery for that purpose:

```
select g.*
from goals g
where g.num_goals = (select max(g1.goals) from goals g1 where g1.year = g.year)
```

This would include ties, if any.

Comment: i was wondering if you could clarify what g. meant and g meant, also what g1 means.

Comment: @wavekootah: these are *aliases* for the tables. `g` stands for table `goals` in the outer query, `g1` stand for `goals` in the subquery.

Comment: im not sure what a subquery is and your saying g1 means goals in this case?